# How to remove a certain class under a certain div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, class

I have this code:

```
<li><div class="review-item">
<div class="review-item-thumb"><img width="60" height="60" src="/content/members/av/flags/por-av.png"></div>
<h5>Player <small> Member </small></h5>
<div align="center"></div><font class="fdescrip">No Description!</font></div>
<ul><li><table class="descrip"><tbody><tr><td>
<p><font class="fdescrip">No complete description available.</font></p>
</td></tr></tbody></table></li></ul></li>
```

I want to remove the `font class="fdescrip"` under `div class="review-item"` ONLY. I can make both of them dissapear (with `$('tag').removeAttr("class");)`but not just one of them as I don't want the second one`<p><font class="fdescrip">No complete description available.</font></p>` to be removed.

Any help will be very appreciated!
Thanks.

Comment: Why not simply `...removeClass('fdescrip')`?

Comment: Please take the time to format your code better when you post it.

Comment: because i need the content of the font tag to be gone

Comment: This is some really bad layout, don't expect things to go your way with a layout like that, rethink it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removes just the CSS class:

```
$('.review-item > .fdescrip').removeClass('fdescrip');
```

Removes element from DOM:

```
$('.review-item > .fdescrip').remove();
```

Clears the elements content if it's only plain text but leaves it in the DOM:

```
$('.review-item > .fdescrip').text('');
```

Comment: works for class but i need the content of the font tag to be gone

Comment: Do you need the element to stay, but be empty, or can it be removed from the DOM entirely?

Comment: I need it to be removed entirely.

Comment: See my new edit, I included how to remove from DOM or clear the text.  Was on my phone so the formatting was a little weird, should be fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

You can select the **first child** using,

```
$('div.review-item .fdescrip:first-child').removeAttr('class');
```

This way, the jQuery will be applied to the first `fdescrip` in the div of review-item and not to any other!

Here is a fiddle for this: http://jsfiddle.net/afzaal_ahmad_zeeshan/Vw7Q8/

Fiddle doesn't remove the class, but it adds there! So you can change it to `removeAttr`.

#### Reference:

http://api.jquery.com/first-child-selector/

Comment: Both of his fdescrip items were descendants, so this would still select all of them.

Comment: Have a look at it now bro :) @cjd82187..:)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".review-item .fdescrip").removeClass('fdescrip');
```